# Как получить выбраный элемент в ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как в ViewModel получить то, что выбрал юзер в ComboBox?
Я не мог найти как это сделать, если я заполняю список внутри XAML, а не из кода

```
    <ComboBox Name="carrierFrequency" SelectedIndex="0">
        <TextBlock>100kHz</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>200kHz</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>300kHz</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>400kHz</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>500kHz</TextBlock>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: [WPF - MVVM - ComboBox SelectedItem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11062297/312041)

Comment: Вы заполняете ComboBox текстблоками, а не строковыми значениями. Лучше используйте `ComboBoxItem`. А еще лучше привязки и шаблоны.

Comment: зачем юзать `wpf` если не привязываешься к данным?

Comment: Просто зачем захламлять код статичными данными?